# Cannot Sort an Array of Object using Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, interface, comparable

So in this class I am trying to create an array of Starship objects and then use Arrays.sort to sort them by length, printing the array before and after. My implementation of Comparable seems correct and I've supplied a compareTo() method, but I'm getting the following error as if I'm not providing the correct implementation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Starship cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
at Starship.main(Starship.java:44)
```

I've searched all over and haven't found this problem. Many, many thanks to anyone who can help with my code below!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Starship implements Comparable<Starship> {
//fields
private String name;
private String captain;
private int length;
//methods
public Starship (String name, String captain, int length){
    this.name=name;
    this.captain=captain;
    this.length=length;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String getCaptain(){
    return captain;
}
public int getLength(){
    return length;
}
public String toString(){
    return "(ship="+name+", captain="+captain+", length="+length+"m)";
}

@Override
public int compareTo (Starship other){
    if (length<other.length) return -1;
    else if(length>other.length) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
//test


public static void main(String[] args){
    Starship[] ships= { 
                       new Starship("Enterprise-D", "Jean-Luc Picard", 643), 
                       new Starship("Serenity", "Malcolm Reynolds", 82),
                       new Starship("Galactica", "William Adama", 1445), 
                       new Starship("Millennium Falcon", "Hans Solo", 35)
                       };
    System.out.println("The ships:");
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        System.out.println(ships[i].toString());
    }

    Arrays.sort(ships);

    System.out.println("After sorting:");
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    System.out.println(ships[i].toString());
    }


}
}
```

Comment: What error? What does it do that it shouldn't be doing?

Comment: Why did you write your own `Comparable` interface? Use Java's, `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: I just edited to include the error. The code should be sorting the Starships based on length. I should have specified! Thanks!

Comment: Recompile your code; it runs without error here.

Comment: @Pillar I'm not sure what you mean about writing my own interface, or what I would have to do differently to use Java's java.lang.Comparable

Comment: Do you have an interface named `Comparable` other than `java.lang.Comparable` in your classpath at compilation time and runtime?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've done so many times! I'm not sure what's the problem but thank you!!

Comment: @Pillar I no longer have such an interface in the class path, though I did before and got the same error both times!

Comment: [Your code runs fine.](http://ideone.com/NvAEfZ) It fails if you have an interface named `Comparable` that shadows `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I deleted all of the class files in my directory and recompiled. For some reason it works now. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Can you post the working code and what you did to make it work? That will help future queries from potential seekers.